# android google maps location

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I want to save marker's location to sp so every time i open the app i load the markers.

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor putDouble(final SharedPreferences.Editor edit, final String key, final double value) {
    return edit.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value));
}

double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue) {
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, Double.doubleToLongBits(defaultValue)));
}
```

the value returned from the getter is diffrent from my location far away like 200km

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the `getDouble` method, you need to use `Double.longBitsToDouble` to convert it back to a Double, I believe.

```
 double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue) { 
       return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, 
                       Double. longBitsToDouble(defaultValue))); 
 }
```

Comment: Can you give me example

Comment: `double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue) {
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, Double. longBitsToDouble(defaultValue)));
}`

Answer (score 0):

**Double.longBitsToDouble()** will Returns the double value corresponding to a given bit representation. 
so you try this

```
double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue) 
{
return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, Double.longBitsToDouble(defaultValue)));
}
```

Comment: @Sanoop check updated ans it will ans your question my friend